# Stored procedure To Delete rows then renumber column

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a procedure to DELETE rows from `TBL_1` where `TASK_ID` is between `@FirstID` and `@LastID` and `PROJECT_ID = @PROJECT_ID`

Then renumber `TASK_ID` to be sequential (this is where the problem is)

The `task_ID` must be sequential in order for the grid I am working with to function correctly.

Table structure is

```
ID (int PK), TASK_ID (INT), project_id (INT), other columns
```

I am absolutely clueless how to do this with a stored procedure. I have a method in the front end app that handles this but I know that an SP would be better and I cannot figure out how to approach this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about order by Task_Id

Comment: Sequential based on what? If you can determine that in a query that runs an update, why bother storing it? Just generate the sequence number at query time, then it doesn't have to be run constantly to be up to date.

Comment: In other words, perhaps you aren't yet acquainted with [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: True, I am not acquainted with row_number.

Comment: the task_id column is sequential 1,2,3,4,5....
if I delete 2-4 then the remaining rows 5 must now be 2 and 6 would now be 3

Comment: So I started Playing with ROW_NUMBER() and this looks like it would be part of this solution for sure, thanks Andriy.  
Still lost on how to implement

Comment: (What is the point of the `ID` column? Doesn't `project_id + TASK_ID` form a suitable PK?)

Comment: No as I must use ROWID to link tasks together as TASK_ID changes 
Task_ID is used to show tasks in the correct order but since rows must be deleted or added task_id will always be changing.

Comment: Then I see no purpose for the Task_ID column at all. Why doesn't your app just display the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWID) and not bother keeping this sequential set of task_ids in the table at all?

Comment: Yes yes and YES Mr. Bertrand I thank you sir.

Comment: You can always identify the row(s) to change by the `ID` column, regardless of what fake number you generate to display in the grid at runtime. The extra column just seems like an unnecessary and wasteful complication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TBL_1
(
  Project_ID INT,
  Task_ID INT,
  Description VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID, Task_ID)
);

INSERT dbo.TBL_1(Project_ID, Task_ID, Description)
VALUES(1,1,'Task 1'),(1,2,'Task 2'),(1,3,'Task 3'),
      (1,4,'Task 4'),(1,5,'Task 5'),(1,6,'Task 6');

GO
```

Create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RenumberTasksWithRedundantInformation
  @Project_ID INT,
  @FirstTaskID INT,
  @LastTaskID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DELETE dbo.TBL_1 
    WHERE Project_ID = @Project_ID 
      AND Task_ID BETWEEN @FirstID AND @LastID;

  ;WITH x AS
  (
    SELECT Project_ID, Task_ID, NewTaskID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Task_ID)
    FROM dbo.TBL_1 WHERE Project_ID = @Project_ID
  )
  UPDATE x SET Task_ID = NewTaskID;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Now, call it this way:

```
EXEC dbo.RenumberTasksWithRedundantInformation 
  @Project_ID  = 1, 
  @FirstTaskID = 2, 
  @LastTaskID  = 4;
```

Then run a query:

```
SELECT Project_ID, Task_ID, Description FROM dbo.TBL_1 WHERE Project_ID = 1;
```

Results:

```
Project_ID  Task_ID  Description
----------  -------  -----------
1           1        Task 1
1           2        Task 5
1           3        Task 6
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TBL_1;
```

---

## Now, my point is...

...there isn't really a reason to ever update this Task_ID column once it's been established. You are trying to treat an identifier in the database, and a display item in your front end code, as the same thing. Why can't you just give this query to your front end code:

```
SELECT Task_ID, SequentialID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Task_ID),
  Description FROM dbo.TBL_1 WHERE Project_ID = 1;
```

Now, the UI can *show* the SequentialID column, but when it passes back the IDs to update / delete / what have you, it passes the actual Task_ID stored in the database (which your grid doesn't have to care about, and which users should have no knowledge of). It's an extra layer of abstraction but it prevents a whole lot of unnecessary churn in your table.

What I don't know about is what you plan to do when folks want to delete tasks 1, 3, and 12, or swap tasks 5 and 6...

Comment: Your Point is VALID for sure.  I need to do some testing on this scenario.  I am excited about your point regarding the relevancy of TASK_ID and now am very concerned about the rest of my design as I see it is flawed.  Testing this now.

Comment: Yep ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) will not work as the TASK_ID column is required to show TASKS in the proper order intended by the user.

Comment: @Wiley then change your column name, because it's not a TASK_ID at all, it's a DisplayOrder. The code above my big bold disclaimer will still work to do what you want (when you delete multiple rows). For other use cases, you'll need to start another question I think.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TASK_ID) is redundant.
If user inserts between task_id 5 and 6 task_id 6 must be changed to 7 so that task_id 6 is available for row insert.

Comment: Yes displayOrder is better

Comment: @Wiley I don't know what you mean by redundant - but your new use case (where someone wants to insert a row between 5 and 6) has nothing to do with the question you asked above - which is why I recommend you ask a different question to deal with other scenarios.

Comment: Ok, so the question would be how to maintain displayOrder through inserts and deletes on rowSet 

I guess part of this exercise is teaching me to communicate better as well

Comment: @Wiley there are just certain rules on Stack Overflow - it isn't fair to completely change or expand your question, this is called scope creep or chameleon questions (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169052/guidance-to-avoid-chameleon-behavior)). Your original question is about renumbering after a delete. I think I have addressed that question, on its own, adequately. As it turns out, you need more expansive help with your whole app. That discussion shouldn't be in these comments

Comment: Understood, Thanks for the reprimand. This is the first time I have attempted online participation of any sort. Refer to me as nubWiley if you want.

Comment: @Wiley I have been trying to be nothing but helpful throughout this whole process; I wouldn't exactly call it a reprimand. YMMV.